# How do I get the current location of mobile using GPS Tracker?

Tags: android, gps, location

I need to get my mobile current location using GPS programmatically.
How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a complete explanation of how obtaining the current position in the training pages of the official android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/currentlocation.html).

Comment: link is dead.. please provide the alternate link

Answer (score 2):

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsListener);

LocationListener gpsListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //          

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
```